# How to get time difference for first 10 entries for an entity in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

SQL Table structure:

[image]

```
id -> primary key 
test_id -> id for test 
response_date -> date on which response is received for a test
```

Multiple responses can be present for the same test_id. My aim is to find the response time difference for the first 10 responses (10th response_date - 1st response_date) for a test_id. I tried using the `group by` test_id and `DATEDIFF`, but it didn't work. Please suggest any other appropriate approach.

```
Desired structure:
test_id  |  response_date_difference_for_first_ten_response
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select test_id,
       datediff(max(case when seqnum = 1 then response_date end),
                max(case when seqnum = 10 then response_date end)
               ) as response_date_difference_for_first_ten_response               
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by test_id order by response_date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by test_id;
```

You could also express this as:

```
select test_id,
       datediff(max(response_date),
               nullif(min(response_date), max(response_date))
               ) as response_date_difference_for_first_ten_response               
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by test_id order by response_date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum in (1, 10)
group by test_id;
```

Comment: Getting syntax error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by test_id order by response_date) as seqnum       from t' at line 6 0.494 sec`. I tried the first one. Second one also giving syntax error. On my machine MySql version is 8.0.18.

Comment: @DevenderKumar Both SQL are correct: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=994724ee4a2b601b628a65dd977bc0fc You did something incorrect...

Comment: @DevenderKumar . . . I would only expect that error in an old version of MySQL.

Comment: @Akina Please check this: https://imgur.com/a/vfV9pLw

Comment: @DevenderKumar Edit my fiddle (or create your own) and reproduce your issue. Pictures tells nothing - except the fact that you hide first 4 lines of your code.

Comment: @Akina I haven't hidden any code as you are saying. 1.) https://imgur.com/RHflg5H 2.)https://imgur.com/YcwWUHf  PS: for your satisfaction

Comment: @DevenderKumar If so then this is your client issue. Check these queries using command-line client and ensure.